# Android: make the icon visible after login Activity is success

Tags: android, android-activity

i have a two activities one of them is login activity, when the login is success i have to make an icon visible in second activity initially i made the icon invisible in layout file of second activity ..below is my code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.fyelogin);                    
            etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
            btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
            btnCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
            lblResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

            final ImageView details = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.red); 

            btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

                    if(password.equals("guest")){
                        lblResult.setText("password successful.");

              // details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                    } else {
                        lblResult.setText("password doesn't match.");

                    }                                      
                    finish();}});
```

i am struck, how can i call the second activity and make icon visible from login activity..Any suggestions is appreciated

Comment: How about using Intent to call 2nd acitivity and use `Intent.putExtra(boolean auth)` to tell 2nd acitivity if login was successfull?

Comment: iam triggering the login activity from a listener...this listener is used in one adapter..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the activity which you put icon in it. (i called as act1)

create a holder class (parameters.java) put it in the class

static boolean isIconvisible;

in your login activity

```
if(password.equals("guest")){
   lblResult.setText("password successful.");
   parameters.isIconvisible="false"  // change the value of it
}
```

act1 onCreate

```
if(parameters.isIconvisible==false){
    details.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
else
{
    details.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

[image]

Comment: actually i have an activity which has a list view                 
when i clcik the list view it fires and intent that is login acitivity ..
here when the login is succes i have to come back to present screen and 
make the icon vivsible..which is in invisible previously

Comment: is that icon is on list item.

Comment: @Mufiz  no..it on headerpart which is common for all screens

Comment: @talhakosen ..your code is kind of working...but when i place the variable in adapter (not activity) its giving null pointer exception at line  details.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: You dont howto do that in adapter. When you click an item in listview,  you are going login activity is it true ?? if it is after come back to the previous activity (which has the listview). Just check that variable.

Comment: @talhakosen wow my implemention is exactly as your daigram..yes when i click listview i goto loginscreenn and after successful login cameback to list view with icon..tried your above code but when the app is strating the icon is visible even though i made it invisible in xml layout file

Comment: i didn't get you what you meant by "create a holder class (parameters.java) put it in the class"

Comment: I mean just create a class and named xxx.java, public class Parameters{ static boolean isIconvisible=false; }. Then you can use the static variable to check visibilty

Comment: yeahh i did...i dont see any difference...what is the use of creating the parameter class..iam soory i am confused

Comment: Ok, i got your problem  now, wait pls

Comment: look at that project you will catch it :)  https://dl.dropbox.com/u/68130108/ListViewGoLogin.rar

Comment: i made changes according to your code but still not able to get the icon visible....i guess since iam going from  login activity back to already loaded activity ..i need to forcefully load the first activity using intent in loginactivity and placing imgvisibility status in putextras.....correct me if i am wrong...i will try your code once again and will get back to you....

Comment: Goto bin folder and install apk to your device then you will see how it is work

Comment: @ talhakosen..Thank you for your example app...mine is working perfectly..thank you so much

Comment: sure..one query ,how to make the listview disable from clicking after icon is appeared..plz give some suggestion...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20377/discussion-between-talhakosen-and-teekib)

Comment: hi sorry i was out my id veldurty.hari@gmail.com, i am available now

Answer (score 1):

boolean iconStatus=false;

if password successful set a boolean variable

```
iconStatus=true;
```

Pass A value in intent like

```
Intent intenet=new Intenet(context,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("icon_status",iconStatus);
```

in In second activity onCreate

```
boolean iconStatus=false;

Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();

if(bundle!=null)
{
iconStatus=true;
}

if(iconStatus)
{
    imageView.setVisibility(View.visible);
}
```

Comment: iam triggering the login activity from a listener...this listener is used in one adapter..

Comment: is that icon is a list item

Comment: If you always add the inconStatus boolean to the intent's Bundle (extras), whether true or false, getIntent().getExtras() will never return null. So iconStatus will always be true in the second activity.